# Create a dummy variable by personid

Tags: python, pandas

I have a time series dataset with individuals and dates.  I would like to create a dummy variable, "newpers", which assumes the value 1 for the the first time, chronologically, the id shows up in the dataset.  For example, if a simplified dataset looked like:

```
personid     yearmo
       1 2004-05-01
       1 2004-06-01
       2 2004-05-01
       2 2004-06-01
```

What I would like to produce is something like:

```
personid     yearmo newpers
       1 2004-05-01       1
       1 2004-06-01       0
       2 2004-05-01       1
       2 2004-06-01       0
```

Sorry if this is easy but I've been going in circles and I'm stumped.  I've been trying to groupby/sort to pull the first chonological date for each person.  The dummy variable could then be `newpers=(yearmo==firstmo)` but I can't seem to get the groupby/sort to not throw an error.

Comment: `select personid, min(yearmo) from yourtable group by personid` will give you those "first" records, you can then use that data set to update newpers=1 for matching records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work (assuming sorted by personid, yearmo)

```
df['newpers'] = df.personid != df.personid.shift(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `shift` method to look backward in the dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], 
    'B': np.random.random_integers(low=0, high=10, size=10)
})
df['A_'] = df['A'].shift()  # each row will contain the previous value of A
df['new_A'] = df.apply(lambda row: int(row['A'] != row['A_']), axis=1)

   A   B  A_  new_A
0  1  10 NaN      1
1  1   3   1      0
2  1   8   1      0
3  2   6   1      1
4  2   4   2      0
5  3   2   2      1
6  3   4   3      0
7  3   1   3      0
8  3   0   3      0
9  3   1   3      0
```